# Angular 2 offline desktop application with service worker

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker

I'm new to angular 2 and I've been assigned to develop an  web application that can be converted to a desktop application (should work in windows and Mac platforms) and should be able to work offline if required.

I'm planning to develop an Angular 2 application with Electron.js or NW.js so that it can be converted to desktop apps in both both platforms

And for offline support I'm planning to get the support of angular service worker library.

My problem is that Angular service worker is for mobile apps. Any idea on how it behaves in desktop applications?

And any issues you found in my approach and any suggestions for improvements?

Comment: web applications work across any platform... i dont understand what you mean by converted to a desktop application

Comment: It should have the capability ow working off line. For an example the user should have the capability to open the app, and start working when there is no internet connection. Can not do that with the web app since at least the page has to be loaded in the browser before going off line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have two bootstrap files, one for your electron app and the other one for your web app, just create a build for each one.

You can share all the code, but remember, you need to watch really close which code is intended for your electron app because it won't work on your web app, as an example trying to read a file from the system.

The service worker will do the job on both apps, electron and web.

Here you have a nice example of service workers:

https://coryrylan.com/blog/fast-offline-angular-apps-with-service-workers

Comment: Thanks I'll read the content of the link. I thought  of having a one app, an electron app, since it will work both online and off line.